# WiX installer - change the install path

Tags: c#, wix, installation

I have a WiX installer and i need to change install path by my specific path. I looked this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799518/wix-change-the-default-install-path). But i don't understand the solution because my installation path is very specific and not a basic folder [system folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa370905.aspx#system_folder_properties).

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Application test"/>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Anybody can explain to me how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a tip to change by a specificly path. The solution is start from the root of WINDOWSVOLUME.

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"> 
   <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
        <Directory Id="SUB_FOLDER" Name="Name of sub-folder".>
          <...>
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="My Application Name"/>
          </...>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
</Directory>
```